# How can I acquire Temperature using TI SimpleLink Wi-Fi CC3220SF-LAUNCHXL and display the temperature in 430BOOST-ADS1118 Boosterpack?

Tags: temperature, code-composer

Energia returns an error

> "Can't compile for boardCC3220"

So we are unable to get temperature data from ADS1118. We are also facing same issue in CCS V7.3 with SDK downloaded for CC3220. We have succesfully done temperature logging with Arduino MAX6675 and k type thermocouple. We just want to get temperature data from a ktype thermocouple via ADS1118 and print to Serial. Please help.

Comment: This link retales to the problem...  (https://www.element14.com/community/message/230824/l/re-ccscc3220sf-launchxl-unable-to-get-temperature-data-from-ads1118-using-energia-and-ccs#230824) Please help......

Comment: Please... somebody help... It's been 4 months... Nobody knows???

Comment: Does anyone know where I can get answers???

Comment: Please reply...

Comment: Please, anyone know the answer???